# Nested Queries With Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I need to achieve a nested query in Laravel. I'm able to do 1 nested query but I don't know how to continue nesting the others.

**What I'd like to happen...**

```
 Select count(*) from  Table1 where idX in 
     (Select id from Table2 where idY in
     (Select id from Table3 where name ='name')) group by x
```

**What I am able to do...**

```
DB::table("attendance")->select(DB::raw('COUNT(*) as internship_count'))
    ->whereIn('student_id',function($query){
    $query->select('id')->from('student');
})->groupBy('internship_id')->get();
```

**What I expect...**

```
  DB::table("attendance")->select(DB::raw('COUNT(*) as internship_count'))
        ->whereIn('student_id',function($query){
            $query->select('id')->from('student')
                ->whereIn('course_id',function($query2){
                    $query2->select('id')->from('courses')
                        ->where('name','=','course-name');
                })
        })
      ->groupBy('internship_id')->get();
```

Comment: Side note: Your query can be done with JOIN's which i assume is alot easier in Laraval.. With the laravel's native join and count functions..

Comment: yes, but in my perspective "joins" performances are pretty bad compared with nested queries

Comment: "yes, but in my perspective "joins" performances are pretty bad compared with nested queries" iám almost 100% sure then you don't index correctly or how laravel framework generates queries sometimes is the blame i geuss for most of your performance issues.